# Gradle can not run ng build on MacOs since last MacOs update (Apple Silicon)

Tags: angular, eclipse, macos, gradle

I am trying to run ng build via a gradle job from within Eclipse on MacOs (Apple Silicon). Ng is installed via homebrew in zsh. Because gradle itself seems not to recognize ng, when running via

```
commandLine 'ng build'
```

I thougt it is a problem that Gradle does not recognize my ZSH Path.

Therefore I created a shell script with the following content:

```
#! /bin/zsh 
ng build
```

This seems to work until latest MacOs update. When I try to run it via the following gradle task:

```
task ngBuild(type:Exec) {
    group 'frontendTasks'
    println "Do npm build"
    workingDir 'src/main/resources/frontend-angular/'
    commandLine './runNgBuild.sh'
}
```

I get the following error:

```
./runNgBuild.sh:2: command not found: ng

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ngBuild'.
> Process 'command './runNgBuild.sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
```

Comment: Did you try taking the binary from your `node_modules` directly using `npx`? This should be safer anyway since you will use the `@angular/cli` version required in your `package.json`. (i.e. change `ng build` to `npx ng build`)

Comment: Good idea, but this seems not to work either. I am just getting a similiar error to the one before.  Now it says: ./runNgBuild.sh:2: command not found: npx

Comment: `npx` comes shipped with `npm` since `5.2.0` (~mid 2017). You either have a more fundamental problem here (e.g. node not installed?) or some serious upgrading to do.